# Go project containing Typescript AWS-CDK directory has cluttered go.mod file

Tags: go, aws-cdk, directory-structure

I have a Go project containing a Typescript AWS-CDK directory to define the Stack that contains the Go binary.

The simplest project for this example is:

```
mkdir example
cd example
mkdir infrastructure
cd infrastructure
cdk init app --language typescript
cd ..
go mod init example
go mod tidy
```

At this point, `go.mod` is full of `aws-cdk-go` references (despite the fact I'm using Typescript).  Ideally, `go.mod` shouldn't have any dependencies at this point.  It appears that there are several Go files buried in the `node_modules/aws-cdk/....` path that may be influencing `go mod tidy`.

I'm not yet interested in using the Go CDK libraries.  Besides throwing all of my Go code into a subfolder and only running `go mod init` in that subfolder, is there a way to prevent `go mod tidy` from referencing those buried files?

Comment: Hi! I am trying to achieve the same with GO and CDK in Typescript. Is all your cdk code contained inside infra folder? Is there any other setting required or cdk can work independently confined in a folder?

Comment: @AnkitRaonka I actually abandoned using the Typescript version of the CDK.  Instead, I'm using the Go version `github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdk/v2` and creating a stack using `github.com/aws/aws-cdk-go/awscdklambdagoalpha/v2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-an-additional-gomod-exclude-unnecessary-content-do-modules-have-the-equivalent-of-a-gitignore-file

> An empty go.mod in a directory will cause that directory and all of
> its subdirectories to be excluded from the top-level Go module.

In the `infrastructure` directory, `touch go.mod` creates an empty file and if I `go mod tidy` in the root folder, the `go.mod` file only contains the modules my project actually uses.

Answer (score 0):

`go mod init` [looks for configuration files](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-init) and, if found, installs the modules.

Avoid this "helpful" behaviour by running `go mod init` [Edit] <s>before cdk init app</s> in a subdirectory:

```sh
# ...
npx cdk init app --language typescript
cd ..
mkdir src
cd src
go mod init example
go mod tidy
cd ..
```

This creates an empty `go.mod`, as expected.

Comment: `go mod tidy` is the step that is causing all of the cdk modules to show up in the `go.mod` file.  When I `go mod init`, it doesn't have these modules.

Comment: @TimReddy - You are right.  I edited the answer.  This time confirmed the expected result with `go mod tidy` ;)